# Is there a way to get a python value to an html <p>?

Tags: python, html, xlrd

I'm making a somewhat simple python script + html site to get simple values from an Excel document.
I was able to use the "xlrd" library to get the exact cell which I needed and used a print statement to see if it worked.

Right now, I can't find a way to use that python value and get it inside a simple "h1 or p" in html.

Many people use "django" or "flask" to work with python and html, but I can't find the time to learn "django" or "flask", and need a quick solution (if it's even possible using vanilla python and html).

Here is the simple python code:

```
import xlrd

location = ("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/website-client/excels/FTHAgg.xlsx")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(location)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# For row 0 and column 0
print(sheet.cell_value(4, 0))
```

And here is the html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="rh.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans+JP&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a class="active" href="rh.html">RH</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/gvt.html">GVT</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/fth.html">FTH</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    # here is where i'd like the paragraph containing the value go
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you planning to do with the HTML? Serve it to a web browser? Save it as a local file? Something else?

Comment: I'd like to present a python value to <p> in an existing html file

Comment: Are you want to add value to local html file or live html file? Solutions could be different based on the situation.

Comment: local, not live

Comment: I guess a quick solution would be to use jinja or some similar template engine, but it depends on what are you actually asking.